# C: why in K&R is written that EOF does not fit in char?

Tags: c++, c

I just started studying *The C programming Language* and I need to ask you this question:

I know that the function `getchar()` gives you an integer that is always positive.
for example for `\t` the result is 32 and this value can be store in char.

K&R's book say that EOF that is `-1` can't be stored in char (but in realty it can).
Anyway it doesn't work with unsigned char.

The explenation that I give to this is that char can store values from `-127` to `127`, so it can contain `-1`, but unsigned char can only go from `0` to `255`, so it can't contain `-1`.

Am I right? And why K&R's book says that?

Comment: "for example for \t the result is 32" Do you mean 9?

Comment: I have not read it. But perhaps they talk about the conceptual value of eof which must represent a "not a character value". -1 is its value in a context where chars are from 0 .. 255. If you represent chars by -128 .. 127, obviously the integer value of EOF must be something different.

Comment: There are 256 different characters that can be read. That means each value a char can take is a valid result. That's why EOF does not fit in a char and why getchar returns int.

Comment: The `char` type was unsigned back in the K&R days.  Some compilers still have a [compat option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0d294k5z.aspx) to rewind the clock.

Answer (score 2):

> K&R's book say that EOF that is -1 can't be stored in char (but in realty it can).

The standard does not specify whether `char` is `signed` or `unsigned` type. It's up to an implementation to decide whether `char` is `signed` or `unsigned` type. For an implementation that uses an `unsigned` type for `char`, you cannot hold the value `-1` in a `char`. `int` is a `signed` type and it can hold the value `-1`. That's the reason for `int` being the return type of `getchar`, `getc`, and `fgetc`.

Answer (score 1):

The `getc` function in C accesses a stream, and returns either non-negative byte value in the range 0 to `UCHAR_MAX`, or else a value equal to the `EOF` constant, which is negative. It is returned as a type `int` value.

These two data ranges cannot fit into the type `char`, whether it is signed or unsigned. The `EOF` value, if stored in a `char`, creates an ambiguity because it clashes with a valid byte value. The range `0` to `UCHAR_MAX` already claims every possible value in a character type.

Suppose we're in the now nearly ubiquitous 8 bit, two's complement world. A signed `char` has a value from -128 to 127. That range covers -1: the value -1 could occur in a stream of `char`-s.  An `unsigned char` ranges from 0 to 255. The value -1 doesn't occur; but if -1 is converted `unsigned char`, it will turn into 255. That is a valid byte value. (Note that `EOF` isn't necessarily -1, but similar reasoning applies to other negative values. ISO C only says that `EOF` is negative. It could be `INT_MIN`!)

If you do capture the return value of `getc` using a `char`, then you have to test `ferror(stream) || feof(stream)` every time you see a value which compares equal to `EOF`. If this test is false, then the `EOF` is actually a byte value and you must treat it accordingly.

(This must also be done on a platform where it happens that `sizeof (int) == 1`).